# Convert angularjs service into angular 2 service when we have a service injected another service

Tags: angularjs, angular

I see a code that a service (BService) injected into another service(AService):

```
(function() {
    "use strict"

    class AService {

        constructor(BService) {
            this.BService = BService;
        }

        static AFactory(BService) {
            return new AService(BService);
        }
    }
    AService.AFactory.$inject = ['BService'];
    angular.module('test').service('AService', AService.AFactory);
})();
```

1. What is `AService.AFactory.$inject` doing? Why We need AFactory here? Can I remove AFactory here?
2. I want to convert above service into following angular 2 service. Am I right?

   ```
       import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
       import { BService } from './b.service'

       @Injectable()
       export class AService {

           constructor(private BService: BService) {

           }


       }

       angular.module('test').service('AService', AService);
   ```

Comment: AService.AFactory is antipattern. The case needs some explanation. If you need to use this file in A1 and A2 app simultaneously, that's one thing. Another thing is when you're converting it to A2 and don't need to use it in A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. as stated at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation:

> To allow the minifiers to rename the function parameters and still be able to inject the right services, the function needs to be annotated with the `$inject` property. The `$inject` property is an array of service names to inject.

So, the code also could be written as:

```
angular.module('test').service('AService', ['BService', function(bService) {
  // AService logic goes here,
  // injected BService may be used under bService variable
  ...
}]);
```

showed by your code is just the same code implemented with new JS class and static method `AFactory`, which is passed to `test` module via its class: `AService.AFactory`

2.Your code is correct except for the last line which is redundant. Here is an [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#!#why-di) about dependency injection. See example of service at `src/app/heroes/hero.service.ts`:
      [1](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#!#why-di): https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#!#why-di

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HEROES }     from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes() { return HEROES; }
}
```

then, the service need to be 'provided' from component or module (src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts in the above [link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#!#why-di)):

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';

import { HeroService }        from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  template: `
    <h2>Heroes</h2>
    <hero-list></hero-list>
  `
})
export class HeroesComponent { }
```

in angular 2+, modules are defined with `@NgModule` annotation and services are registered similar to components unde `providers` property. See example with `UserService` registered (src/app/app.module.ts from the [link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#!#why-di) above):

```
// imports here

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    /* . . . */
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService,
    { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: HERO_DI_CONFIG }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

your ng2 code could be rewritten as:
    // a.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BService } from './b.service'

@Injectable()
export class AService {

    constructor(private bService: BService) {

    }
}
```

and registration in any module:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AService }  from ''./a.service'';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    /* . . . */
  ],
  providers: [ AService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```